# Baking normals is going how it should

Tags: texturing, texture-baking, normal-map

When baking normals after retopology of an high poly mash the map looks horrible and only some of the details get baked

### [image]

The Link to the drive with the blend file

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1V3KDf89FSRVBQtNcGoL77mng6kXGrjv1?usp=sharing

Comment: Well what do your meshes look like?  You've at least got normals that look like normals baking there, so I can't tell that they're not supposed to look that way.

A screenshot of the UV map would also be useful I think - it could just be squashed UV mapping leading to equally squashed normal baking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be alot of issues with this blend file.

First off, I can't tell because it seems like the baking settings were reset, or maybe you weren't baking in Blender, in any case, you want to check this setting and make sure it is high enough to envelop the entire HP mesh.

[image]

This setting is telling Blender how far out from a HP mesh to "look" for normal map details.

[image]

If it's set too low then it will stop looking before it reaches the details you want to capture in the normal map.

On that note you want to make sure that your low poly and high poly meshes match each other as closely as possible. There are a lot of spots where the difference is way too much to tolerate. Usually I set the material of one of the meshes to something really bright so you can see the difference very clearly.

[image]

I like to use a Shrinkwrap Modifier to get it really close, and then tweak it after that to make sure it's perfect.

[image]

Finally, I would highly consider going back to an earlier version of this HP mesh and rework it from the ground up. It looks like you made it with a mirror modifier but didn't use "Clipping" so it's not even merged down the middle axis.

[image]

There are alot of areas with extreme pinching and bizarre topology that are not going to look great in the bake.

[image]

[image]

A lot of non-manifold geometry, which in general is a bad idea but when normal baking is only going to cause problems.

[image]

Generally speaking you don't want to have one thin strip of faces welded into another set of faces like this.

[image]

Then finally there are a number of other spots where there are either floating geometry or gaping holes into the backside of your mesh.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

You have to remember that your bake is going to basically take a "screenshot" of your high-poly mesh as it is, flaws and all. If you have weird shading errors, floating geometry, twisted faces and so on, your bake is going to capture that exactly. You want you HP mesh to look as flawless as possible before you try to bake it.

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually it is a very old mesh that i did in my early days in blender and it was the only thing i had to practice retopology, i will try to make it again and bake new normals. thank you again.